# IEnumerable constructor overload

Tags: c#, ienumerable, enumeration

I have some custom list which is based on `IEnumerable<T>`. Now I want to overload the constructor and do some custom stuff with the initial list I get.

```
//Constructor
public CustomList(IEnumerable<T> collection) : base(collection)
{
    //do some stuff with the collection e.g. iterate
    foreach(T obj in collection)
    {
        //do some stuff with obj
    }
}
```

Is it even possible to do so? Because IEnumerable can only be enumerated once at `base(collection)`, but the loop will fail, I guess.

**EDIT:**
since it is not completely clear for everyone: My base class is `IEnumerable<T>` and `IEnumerable` can only be enumerated once in my case.

Comment: What is your base class?

Comment: Have you actually tried it? I see no problem with what you have here. I don't know what makes you think `IEnumerable can only be enumerated once`.

Comment: @MattBurland - That's true for some collections.

Comment: Are you talking something like this CSHARK 
`public static void ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection, Action<T> action)
{
    foreach (var item in collection)
        action(item);
}`

Comment: Nope, this would also require a second enumeration and the first one happens in the base constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your base class is `List<T>`, then the base constructor adds all the items to the current object. So you could do the following as often as you want:

```
foreach (T obj in this) { }
```

But I've heard it's a bad idea to inherit from `List<T>`, that you should implement `IList<T>` instead, even if it is just a wrapper around `List<T>`. I just can't remember why that is.

Comment: You're right, with List<T> I would have no problem, because it can be enumerated multiple times. But I have an IEnumerable<T> which can only be enumerated once in my case.

Comment: @CShark I think you misread this answer. Either that, or I misread your comment. This answer looks at the items in your class, not the items in the enumerable. It relies on the `base(collection)` constructor making the items available for later use, so it enumerates `collection` only once.

Comment: Ah yes. I was irritated by the List<T>. But this answer is completely right and works.